# Changing constraints constants

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a function that anchors the views to other views easily without having to write a lot of code. The function is called like this:

```
    view.anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?,
    left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, 
    bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, 
    right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, 
    topConstant:CGFloat?, 
    leftConstant: CGFloat?, 
    bottomConstant: CGFloat?, 
    rightConstant: CGFloat?, 
    widthConstant: CGFloat?, 
    heightConstant: CGFloat?)
```

Basically I just put in anchors for other views, add constants if needed and adjust width and height. All parameters are optional

This works great and it saves lots of space and code, however at the moment I want to change the `heightConstant` in one of my views and the only way that I have seen people changing constraints is by creating a variable for each constraint like this:

```
var heightConstraint = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 20, multiplier: 1)
```

and then change it later on by accessing the variable.

Is there any other way of updating constraints other than this way or do I have to get rid of my function and start using variables

Comment: Since your function has a list of optionals, couldn't you pass everything *but* the height constraint to it? Let you function create everything it can, then create one more constraint - a "named" one - for height. For example, pass the function top, leading, and trailing.Then outside the function create the height.

Comment: `var heightConstraint = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 20, multiplier: 1)` doesn't compile! your `20` shouldn't be a `float` it should be of type `NSLayoutDimension`

Comment: you could just access your constraint's `constant` property and change it. You may need to update your constraints. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241191/nslayoutconstraint-constant-not-updating-after-setting)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you start using variables to save the constraints.

You *could* go digging around in the `constraints` variable on your view, find the right constraint there, and then update it, but that is imo messy code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way change constraints take outlet of that UI and then simply write where ever you want to change

```
@IBOutlet weak var constraintsName:NSLayoutConstraint!
//Put this code viewdidLOad,didAppear or etc method....
self. constraintsName.constant = value
```